# Как сделать виртуальный тур по зданию из панорамных фото?

Tags: android, панорамы, virtualtour

Нужно сделать виртуальный тур по зданию. Например есть длинный коридор с дверьми в кабинеты.Сделано несколько панорамных снимков 360' как самого коридора, так и кабинетов. Необходимо сделать обзор этих панорам с возможностью добавления на них кнопок перехода (на дверях, чтобы зайти в кабинет, либо в продолжении коридора, чтобы перейти к следующей точке).

Как такое можно реализовать в Android ?

Comment: Поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, какие подходы используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.

Comment: @Kromster, я просто не могу понять, каким образом можно реализовать функционал добавления стрелок/кнопок для перехода между панорамами.

Comment: @NikotinN Если проблема в этом, то сформулируйте это в вопросе.

Answer (score 9):

Код в этом посте - продолжение [другого ответа про 3d Панораму](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1001178/188366)

---

Решение на `WebGL/Three.js`, то же самое можно сделать на `OpenGL ES` или же использовать это решение в `WebView`.

`Three.js` я взял чтобы не заморачиваться с моделью сферы и ее текстурными координатами. тут это уже реализовано.

Берем сферу, выворачиваем её наизнанку, чтобы текстура накладывалась изнутри. Камера находится в центре сцены и вращается при помощи драга мышкой, так же работает зум колёсиком.

Для позиционирования активных зон тут используется дополнительная текстура-трафарет, в которой разными цветами-идентификаторами отмечены области.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее используется `color picking` - определяются текстурные координаты точки под мышкой, при помощи них берется цвет с текстуры-трафарета и если этот цвет отличается от нуля - значит мы навели на активную зону и можем показать тултип.

Названия объектов берутся по ключам, соответствующим цветам активных зон в трафарете.

Подсветка осуществляется по примерно такой же логике, но уже во фрагментном шейдере.

Если по кликам на зоны менять текстуры, то получится эффект хождения между точками, с которых сняты панорамы.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/104/three.min.js"></script>
<script>
  let camera, scene, renderer, mesh, material, e, objects,
      imgData, uv, info, lon = 0, lat = 0;

  var mouseDown = {};
  var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
  var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  init({
    texture: "https://i.imgur.com/jevL9av.jpg",
    stencil: "https://i.imgur.com/NUKbrbl.png",
    objects: {
      "255,0,0": "Розетка 1",
      "245,0,0": "Окно 1",
      "235,0,0": "Лоток",
      "225,0,0": "Коробка",
      "215,0,0": "Ящик стола",
      "205,0,0": "Розетка 2",
      "195,0,0": "Камин",
      "185,0,0": "Окно 2",
      "175,0,0": "А здесь был лось",
      "165,0,0": "Стол"
    }
  })

  function init(json) {
      objects = json.objects;
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1100);
      camera.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      let geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(500, 60, 40);
      geometry.scale(-1, 1, 1);
      material = createMaterial(json.texture, json.stencil);
      scene.add(mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material));
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setPixelRatio(devicePixelRatio);
      renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
      document.body.append(renderer.domElement);
      info = document.createElement('div');
      info.id = 'info';
      document.body.append(info);
      addEventListener('mousedown', onPointerStart);
      addEventListener('mousemove', onPointerMove);
      addEventListener('mouseup', onPointerUp);
      addEventListener('wheel', onDocumentMouseWheel);
      addEventListener('touchstart', onPointerStart);
      addEventListener('touchmove', onPointerMove);
      addEventListener('touchend', onPointerUp);
      addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);
      animate();
  }

  function createMaterial(img, stencil) {
      let textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
      let stencilImage = new Image();
      stencilImage.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
      stencilImage.src = stencil;
      stencilImage.onload = function() {
          canvas.width = stencilImage.width;
          canvas.height = stencilImage.height;
          ctx.drawImage(stencilImage,0,0);
          imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      };
      return new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
          uniforms: {
              mouse: { type: "2f", value: mouse },
              texture1: { type: "t", value: textureLoader.load( img ) },
              texture2: { type: "t", value: textureLoader.load( stencil ) }
          },
          vertexShader: `
              varying vec2 vUv;
              void main() {
                  vUv = uv;
                  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
              }`,
          fragmentShader: `
              precision highp float;
              varying vec2 vUv;
              uniform vec2 mouse;
              uniform sampler2D texture1;
              uniform sampler2D texture2;
              void main() {
                  vec4 stencil = texture2D(texture2, vUv);
                  gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, vUv);
                  vec4 c = texture2D(texture2, mouse);
                  if (abs(c.x - stencil.x) < 0.0001 && stencil.x > 0.)
                      gl_FragColor += vec4(0.,0.2,0,0.);
              }`
      })
  }

  function onWindowResize() {
      camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      renderer.setSize( innerWidth, innerHeight );
  }

  function onPointerStart( event ) {
      mouseDown.x = event.clientX || event.touches[ 0 ].clientX;
      mouseDown.y = event.clientY || event.touches[ 0 ].clientY;
      mouseDown.lon = lon;
      mouseDown.lat = lat;
  }

  function raycast(event) {
      var rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      var x = (event.clientX - rect.left)/rect.width,
          y = (event.clientY - rect.top)/rect.height;
      mouse.set(x*2 - 1, 1 - y*2);
      raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
      var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
      if (intersects.length > 0 && intersects[0].uv) {
          material.uniforms.mouse.value = uv = intersects[0].uv;
          if (!imgData)return;
          let y = Math.floor((1-uv.y)*canvas.height);
          let x = Math.floor(uv.x*canvas.width);
          let off = Math.floor(y*canvas.width + x)*4;
          let r = imgData.data[off];
          let g = imgData.data[off+1];
          let b = imgData.data[off+2];
          info.innerHTML = objects[`${r},${g},${b}`];
          info.style.left = event.clientX + 15 + 'px';
          info.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
          info.style.opacity = r+g+b ? 1 : 0;
      }
  }

  function onPointerMove( event ) {
      raycast(e = event);
      if (!mouseDown.x) return;
      let clientX = event.clientX || event.touches[0].clientX;
      let clientY = event.clientY || event.touches[0].clientY;
      lon = (mouseDown.x - clientX)*camera.fov/600 + mouseDown.lon;
      lat = (clientY - mouseDown.y)*camera.fov/600 + mouseDown.lat;
      lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
  }

  function onPointerUp() {
      mouseDown.x = null;
  }

  function onDocumentMouseWheel( event ) {
      let fov = camera.fov + event.deltaY * 0.05;
      camera.fov = THREE.Math.clamp(fov, 10, 75);
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      let phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
      let theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );
      camera.target.x = 0.001*Math.sin(phi)*Math.cos(theta);
      camera.target.y = 0.001*Math.cos(phi);
      camera.target.z = 0.001*Math.sin(phi)*Math.sin(theta);
      camera.lookAt(camera.target);
      e&&raycast(e);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
</script>
<style>
  body{
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  #info {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      color: white;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
      opacity: 0;
  }
</style>
```

---

PS. Такой прием (`color picking`) можно применять в любых 2d/3d приложениях, в том числе и построенных полностью динамически, только и этот трафарет тогда надо в рантайме рисовать, в параллель с основными кадрами.

---

PPS: Привожу ссылки на другие мои ответы, где используется такой же прием, но уже в 2d:

[`java/swing` Как определить что произошел клик по изображению...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985303/188366)

[Клик по картинке на `js`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/962780/188366)

[Адаптивный `canvas` и `hover` на объекте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/988105/188366)

Comment: Если у кого то найдется 2 кадра одного и того же окружения, но снятые с разных точек, я могу доработать пример, чтобы был переход между кадрами

Answer (score 1):

Вам наверняка поможет [Matterport](https://matterport.com/) - на нем массово делают именно то что описано в задаче - в Штатах и Европе уже целевые студии работают.

Answer (score 0):

Tango здесь ни причем. Он используется для сканирования местности путем комбинирования техники computer vision и сенсоров телефона. Если я правильно понял то Вам нужен обычный тур по местности с готовыми снимками в 360. Не могу Вам точно сказать как именно этого добиться но я бы копал в сторону библиотек позволяющих манипулировать фотографиями в 360 градусов. С помощью гироскопа можно отлавливать движение устройства и соответсвенно двигать изображение (примерно так работает просмотр видео в 360 градусов на youtube со смартфона). На счет кнопок чтобы перейти в дргугие панорамы: я думаю возможно сделать мэппинг кнопок к соотвествующему месту на фото, напрмер таже ручка двери. Надеюсь хоть чем то помог.