# Клик по картинке на js

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Как сделать на js клик по картинке? попытался через jquery, но не срабатывает.

```js
var cvs=document.getElementById("canvas"); // подключаем полотно для отображения кода
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d"); 
var image1=new Image(); // добавляем картинку 

image1.src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/08/21/49/lighthouse-3209985_960_720.jpg";  // адрес картинка

function  q92(){ 
    ctx.drawImage(image1,0,0); 
}

image1.onload=q92; // когда картинка загрузится отрисовываем её
image1.class="qwer";

$('.qwer').on("click", function() {// функция которая должна рабоатать при клике но не работает 
  alert("adsads");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="675"></canvas> <!-- полотно где отображается код -->
```

Comment: это canvas вы не сможете это сделать  с canvas-ом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Image`, который Вы создали, не вставлен в DOM страницы. Поэтому щелкнуть по нему - невозможно. Канвас, напротив, является элементом DOM.

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas"); // подключаем полотно для отображения кода

var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

var image1 = new Image(); // добавляем картинку 

image1.src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/08/21/49/lighthouse-3209985_960_720.jpg"; // адрес картинка

function q92() {
  ctx.drawImage(image1, 0, 0);
}

image1.onload = q92; // когда картинка загрузится отрисовываем её

$(cvs).on("click", function() { // функция, которая должна работать при клике, и работает 
  alert("adsads");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="675"></canvas>
```

---

Без канваса:

```js
var image1 = new Image(); // добавляем картинку 
image1.src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/08/21/49/lighthouse-3209985_960_720.jpg"; // адрес картинка
document.body.appendChild(image1);

$(image1).on("click", function() { // функция, которая должна работать при клике, и работает 
  alert("adsads");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: а если будет много картинок? мне нужно именно по определённо это получается по всему полотну

Comment: @Ivan912 А-а-а, это я должен был сам догадаться.

Comment: @Ivan912 Если будет много картинок, то Вы выбрали неправильный подход.

Comment: Извините,за не совсем точное описание, можете пожалуйста показать как это реализовать?

Comment: Да множество картинок и при клике на разные происходят разные события

Comment: @Ivan912 Что "это"? Вы прочитали объяснение в начале ответа?

Comment: а вы можете показать это в пример? просто не совсем понятно как вставить в dom этот элемент возможно нужно добавить что такое var cvs = document.getElementById

Comment: спасибо разобрался дал  лучше

Answer (score 8):

**Определяем в какую конкретно картинку, нарисованную на канве произошел клик.**

Этот метод называется `picking` часто используется в трехмерной графике для определения что же под мышкой, для 2д тоже отлично подходит.

Суть в том, чтобы параллельно с отрисовкой картинок на канве мы формируем дополнительный буфер, в котором интересующие нас объекты (картинки) закодированы разным цветом-идентификатором, а по клику берем цвет по координатам клика из пикинг-буфера.

**UPD: добавил анимацию**

```js
let imagesCanvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let pickingCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
pickingCanvas.width = imagesCanvas.width;
pickingCanvas.height = imagesCanvas.height;
let imgCtx = imagesCanvas.getContext('2d');
let pickCtx = pickingCanvas.getContext('2d');
imgCtx.strokeStyle = 'red';
imgCtx.lineWidth = 4;
let images = ['11', '22','33' ]
let loaded = [];
let current = -1;

// слушатель вешаем на канву
imagesCanvas.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // берем цвет по координатам и вычисляем из него индекс
  var i = pickCtx.getImageData(e.x, e.y, 1, 1).data["0"]-1; 
  current = loaded[i] ? i : -1;
})

load();// загружаем картинки

function load() {
  let name = images.shift();
  let img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  // вызываем загрузку следующей картинки, пока они все не будут загружены, 
  // тут надо предусмотреть onerror, и отрисовку, когда они все загрузятся
  img.onload = () => add() | images.length ? load() : requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  img.src = `https://picsum.photos/id/${name}/150/100`
  
  // добавляем инфо о картинке в массив
  function add() {
    loaded.push({
      name: name, img: img,
      // кодируем индекс картинки в цвет
      pickingColor: `rgb(${loaded.length+1},0,0)`,
      x: 50+loaded.length*120,
      y: 5+30*loaded.length,
      w: img.width, h: img.height
    });
  }
}
let t = 0;
function draw(dt) {
   pickCtx.clearRect(0, 0, imagesCanvas.width, imagesCanvas.height);
   imgCtx.clearRect(0, 0, imagesCanvas.width, imagesCanvas.height);
   loaded.forEach((img, i) => {
      img.x += (dt-t)*(i/10+1)/10;
      img.x = img.x > 600 ? 0 : img.x;
      
      // рисуем картинки на канве
      imgCtx.drawImage(img.img, img.x , img.y, img.w, img.h);
      i === current && imgCtx.strokeRect(img.x, img.y, img.w, img.h);
      
      // заполняем пикинг-буфер такими же по размеру прямоугольниками
      // как и картинки на канве и по тем же координатам
      pickCtx.fillStyle = img.pickingColor;
      pickCtx.fillRect(img.x, img.y, img.w, img.h);
      
   });
   t = dt;
   requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```css
body{margin:0}
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="170"></canvas>
```

связанный ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/988105/188366

Comment: Интересный вариант. И кода мало. Теоретически можно пытаться адаптировать под прозрачность на картинках (при условии, что они с того же домена).

Comment: А вообще, непонятно, зачем вообще ему канвас, если можно просто картинки сложить стопкой.

Comment: @Qwertiy метод конечно не для прямоугольников, я его использую в webgl для mouseover по сценам которые полностью во фрагментном шейдере нарисованы. ибо это практически бесплатно. и под прозрачность адаптировать просто - это надо как в алгоритме порядконезависимой прозрачности - построить списки в тех местах где попало больше одного полупрозрачного объекта

Answer (score 1):

```js
var cvs=document.getElementById("canvas"); // подключаем полотно для отображения кода
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d"); 
var image1=new Image(); // добавляем картинку 

image1.src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/08/21/49/lighthouse-3209985_960_720.jpg";  // адрес картинка

function  q92(){ 
    ctx.drawImage(image1,0,0); 
    image1.click();
}

image1.onload=q92; // когда картинка загрузится отрисовываем её
image1.class="qwer";

$(image1).on("click", function() {// функция которая должна рабоатать при клике но не работает 
  alert("adsads");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="675"></canvas> <!-- полотно где отображается код -->
```

Comment: Автор хочет различать по какой картинке был клик, инфа из комментов к ответу Igor

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, хм.. я не читал. Ну и ладно. На вопрос из вопроса я ответил, а там уже совсем другой вопрос. А потом автор ещё про прозрачность вспомнит и будет совсем жесть. Нет уж)))