# Как определить событие onclick по элементу в canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, координаты

Есть рабочий код:

```
cvs.onmousemove = function() {
  mouseX = event.offsetX;
  mouseY = event.offsetY;
  if (mouseX >= centerPosX(cvs) - centerPosX(restart) && mouseX <= (centerPosX(cvs) - centerPosX(restart)) + restart.width && mouseY >= centerPosY(cvs) && mouseY <= centerPosY(cvs) + restart.height) {

    console.log(mouseX); //Координаты мыши Х
  }
}
```

В данном коде вначале отслеживаются координаты мыши и записываются в переменную. Далее **условие** - если мышь находится в пределах нужных мне координат, то выводим в консоль координаты мыши X

**ВОПРОС:**
Нужно добавить в **условие** код, который будет отслеживать клик по этим координатам. Типа в конце условия должно быть что то типа `&& restart.onclick` (restart - это кнопка(спрайт) по которой надо жать и именно её координаты указаны в условии)

Всё что я пробовал - не работает и гугл не помогает.

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не работает?

Comment: Побовал onclick, click, addEventListener и ничего не работает. Можно поизгалятся и создать еще условия уже в теле функции, но я стараюсь минимизировать код

Comment: Я полагаю, что не работает т.к.канвас, насколько знаю - всего лишь холст, где нет слоёв, а лишь изменения цвета пикселей

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/962780/188366

Answer (score 0):

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

```
cvs.onmousemove = function() {
  mouseX = event.offsetX;
  mouseY = event.offsetY;
  if (mouseX >= centerPosX(cvs) - centerPosX(restart) && mouseX <= (centerPosX(cvs) - centerPosX(restart)) + restart.width && mouseY >= centerPosY(cvs) && mouseY <= centerPosY(cvs) + restart.height) {
    cvs.onclick = function() {
      console.log(`Ура! Работает!`);
    }
  } else {
    cvs.onclick = null;
  }
}
```

В тело функции if я добавил:

```
cvs.onclick = function() {
  console.log(`Ура! Работает!`);
}
```

И добавил к if логический оператор else, который будет убирать отслеживание клика, если курсор не в заданной области.