# Какие существуют стратегии при работе с Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5, vue.js, html5-canvas

С канвасом знаком поверхностно - 
при первом знакомстве столкнулся с таким гайдом в разрезе работы с vue.js:
[Controlling the HTML5 Canvas with Vue.js](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-vue-html5-canvas)

Вопросы:

1. Позволяет ли такой способ работать со слоями канваса - так же как с обычными дом елементами?
   (пока что на практике такого добиться не удалось)
2. Из понимания, что ответ скорее всего будет 'нет' - вытекает следующий вопрос:
   Какие существуют стратегии с точки зрения подходов написания кода - в разрезе того, если стоит задача иметь 100500 разных слоев, при клике на которые - должны происходить какие то действия?
   Каким образом можно навешивать событие на отдельный слой(со своими индивидуальными координатами)?(учитывая что холст будет только 1 к примеру.)
3. Если работать без дополнительных библиотек - на какие моменты в первую очередь необходимо обратить внимания - для ускорения и оптимизации работы?
   (возможно есть какие то режимы например не 2d контекст а WebGl - который будет работать быстрее и т.п.)

Comment: может поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/962780/188366

Comment: webgl быстрее при наличии видео карты, но рисовать на нем не просто..., хотя смотря что, кое что и не очень сложно

Comment: А "слои" - сложные фигуры или круги-квадратики? Просто, никто ведь не мешает анимацию и хитрые фигуры рисовать на канве, а поверх него расположить обычные HTML-блоки, чтобы обрабатывать клики.

Comment: сложные фигуры и их много будет очень.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Позволяет ли такой способ работать со слоями канваса - так же как с обычными дом елементами?

Канвас это холст со всеми вытекающими. Вы можете на нём что-то нарисовать или что-то стереть. Все слои придётся держать в памяти `js`  и перерисовывать по мере необходимости.

> Какие существуют стратегии с точки зрения подходов написания кода - в разрезе того, если стоит задача иметь 100500 разных слоев, при клике на которые - должны происходить какие то действия?

Всё очень зависит от задач. При клике на `canvas` вы можете получить только координаты клика и больше ничего. Всю остальную логику придётся реализовывать самому или брать готовые библиотеки. Главное учтите, что у разных браузеров на разных платформах разные ограничения по количеству одновременно существущих `canvas` и их размеры, так что иногда приходится идти на разные ухищрения: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-multiple-views.html

> Если работать без дополнительных библиотек - на какие моменты в первую  очередь необходимо обратить внимания - для ускорения и оптимизации работы?

Учтите, что `canvas` ничего не знает о физических пикселях и на устройствах с `devicePixelRatio > 1` вам придётся увеличивать размер `canvas` на величину `devicePixelRatio` и подгонять под размер с помощью `css`.

Не существует универсального метода по количеству `canvas` для производительности, на одних платформах дешевле нарисовать фон изображение на нескольких `canvas`, на других дешевле нарисовать всё на одном, на третьих `html` поверх `canvas` будет лучшим выбором. Придётся долго и нудно тестить.

`WebGl` будет однозначно быстрее ибо рэндер будет сразу на видеокарте, но на нём, например довольно гемморойно рендерить шрифты. При этом придётся учиться писать шейдеры. Могу посоветовать хороший ресурс: https://webglfundamentals.org/

Нет никакого легального способа синхронизировать `html` и канвас, а `html` это очень медленно, на мобилках это очень сильно заметно. Если выбьетесь из бюджета по пикселям, то гора веселья вам обеспечена.