# Верстка: круг с пустотой внутри и элементами по кругу

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, svg

Нужна верстка круга с пустотой внутри и элементами вокруг данного круга. С ними в будущем нужно будет взаимодействовать. Ломаю голову уже около 40 минут, `clip-path` не помогает. При наведении каждый элемент должен подсвечиваться красным. Каким образом я могу это выполнить, может предложите какое-нибудь руководство по данному поводу? Или приведете свои примеры?

Очень сильно выручите, прикрепляю скриншот.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790341/creating-a-circular-menu-with-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790341/creating-a-circular-menu-with-css)

Comment: Самый простой способ - SVG, самый интересный - canvas по ссылке от InDevX выше в коменте, есть интересный вариан со skew в той же цепочке [прямая ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60321617/14135825)

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Comment: Заменил метку `jQuery` на `SVG` потому как по моему убеждению без SVG здесь будет много сложнее. Так как на Canvas отлавливать события мыши намного сложнее. Или каждый элемент отрисовывать на отдельном слое с прозрачным фоном. Но проще все таки с помощью одного SVG-элемента. Тем более если это меню, то рендериться должно быстрее.

Comment: Вот хороший пример. Возможно, будет чем-то полезен https://codepen.io/Thijs/pen/yyRBxV

Comment: @Макск, поддерживаю!!! С помощью редактора вектора CorelDraw, например, можно создать любую конфигурацию этого меню, объединить каждую "кнопку" с пиктограммой внутри. В SVG файле назначить каждому элементу свой id и отлавливать события мыши как на обычном элементе HTML. По первой ссылке там весь Canvas отрисовывается сотни раз по событию mousemove, а click даже не прописан - еще одну портянку писать для этого.

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/ZEbdXvJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У меня нету информации о всех остальных пунктах - что это такое

Вам остаётся при наведении на `.circles` пройти по всем внутренним [g](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) методом [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) или может быть через цикл [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) и вставить из выборки этими методами/циклами в `#info` который автоматически стоит в центре так как viewBox у меня в центре композиции...

Так же вам надо вставить вместо emodji свои иконки так как я не нашёл их

Всю демонстрацию увидите ниже

А так же надо обернуть каждый `g` обернуть в тег ссылки [a](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a)

Я максимально приблизил свой ответ к примеру из вопроса

```css
body {
  background: url(https://a.d-cd.net/qgAAAgMWp-A-1920.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  --opacity: 0.7;
  --stroke: 170;
  --size: 20px;
}

svg {
  max-height: 100vh;
}

circle {
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.circles circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, var(--opacity));
  stroke-width: var(--stroke);
  stroke-dasharray: 268 1884;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

.circles text {
  font-size: 70px;
  fill: red;
  text-anchor: middle;
  alignment-baseline: central;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.circles circle:hover,
.doc circle:hover {
  stroke: rgba(255, 0, 0, var(--opacity));
}

.circles .c1 {
  transform: rotate(51.9deg);
}

.circles .c2 {
  transform: rotate(103.3deg);
}

.circles .c3 {
  transform: rotate(154.8deg);
}

.circles .c4 {
  transform: rotate(206.3deg);
}

.circles .c5 {
  transform: rotate(257.6deg);
}

.circles .c6 {
  transform: rotate(309deg);
}

.circles .c7 {
  transform: rotate(0.5deg);
}

.doc circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, var(--opacity));
  stroke-width: var(--stroke);
  stroke-dasharray: 298 3141;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

.doc .text {
  fill: #fff;
  font-size: var(--size);
  text-anchor: middle;
  alignment-baseline: central;
}

.doc .c1 {
  transform: rotate(121deg);
}

.doc .c2 {
  transform: rotate(155.6deg);
}

.doc .c3 {
  transform: rotate(190deg);
}

#info circle {
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, var(--opacity));
}

#info text {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-700 -700 1400 1400" id="svg">
  <g class="circles">
    <g>
      <title>icon1</title>
      <circle r="300" class="c1" />
      <text class="icon1" x="60" y="280"></text>
    </g>
    <g>
      <title>icon2</title>
      <circle r="300" class="c2" />
      <text x="-190" y="235" class="icon2"></text>
    </g>
    <g>
      <title>icon3</title>
      <circle r="300" class="c3" />
      <text class="icon3" x="-290" y="0" ></text>
    </g>
    <g>
      <title>icon4</title>
      <circle r="300" class="c4" />
      <text class="icon4" x="-190" y="-235"></text>
    </g>
    <g>
      <title>icon5</title>
      <circle r="300" class="c5" />
      <text class="icon5" x="60" y="-280"></text>
    </g>
    <g>
      <title>icon6</title>
      <circle r="300" class="c6" />
      <text class="icon6" x="270" y="-110">‍</text>
    </g>
    <g>
      <title>icon7</title>
      <circle r="300" class="c7" />
      <text class="icon7" x="270" y="110"></text>
    </g>
  </g>

  <g class="doc">
    <g>
      <title>Лицензии</title>
      <circle r="500" class="c1" />
      <text class="text" x="-390" y="320">Лицензии</text>
    </g>
    <g>
      <title>Паспорт</title>
      <circle r="500" class="c2" />
      <text class="text" x="-500" y="50">Паспорт</text>
    </g>
    <g>
      <title>Тех паспорт</title>
      <circle r="500" class="c3" />
      <text class="text" x="-460" y="-200">Тех.паспорт</text>
    </g>
  </g>

  <g id="info">
    <circle r="200" />
    <text></text>
    <text></text>
    <text></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это помогло, только как мне вместо text вставить SVG картинку?

Comment: @MADARA вместо text картинку - покажите что это должно быть ? скриншот или как мне узнать - что должно получится

Comment: @MADARA  https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/MWpMedO вот поглянь - у тебя будет тоже самое, в defs вставишь иконки и вызовешь их через use точно так же как я вызвал image - если не понятно - я дополню свой ответ но возможно я буду на работе и не смогу вовермя это  сделать

Comment: @MADARA я добавил иконку в svg - посмотри

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли)

Answer (score 5):

Оказалось, что нет никакой возможности для `canvas` не считывать события мыши на прозрачной области (вроде `pointer-events: fill;` для `SVG`), иначе можно было разместить несколько `canvas` послойно с разными закрашенными областями и отлавливать события только на них.

По этому в коде я создаю константы путей, взятых из `SVG` отдельного элемента.
Прописываю цвета для событий `mousedown` и `mousemove`.

Дополнительно к получению доступа к `canvas#menu` создаю другой элемент `canvas` без добавления его в DOM (`element_detector`). На этом "теневом" холсте вырисовываем фигуры по нашим путям, где фигуры заливаем разным цветом без указания правила evenodd. Размеры полотен и координаты фигур совпадают и по координатам `canvas#menu` можно будет получать данные о цвете в пикселе - точке срабатывания события. Что и производится в функции `detectElement()`.

Главная цель проекта - отловить событие `mouseover` на конкретном элементе меню (фигуре). Но так как это событие будет зарегистрировано на самом элементе canvas единожды, при "входе" на весь вмещающий прямоугольник, то приходится отлавливать каждое событие mousemove на элементе и передавать для обработки в функцию `detectElement`, которая вызывает `drawMenu()` с параметрами, зависящими от полученного цвета условной подложки и события мыши. Одним словом: **реализация `mouseover` на отдельных фигурах `canvas` - крайне неэффективнa**.

Отсюда основной вывод. **Для подобных меню и вообще для отлавливания разных событий на сложных фигурах лучше всего подходит SVG!** Их даже послойно можно разместить друг на друге и получать события мыши только на залитых фигурах.

Ремарка: событие mouseup никак не обрабатывается в `drawMenu()` просто `ctx.fillStyle` не может получить доступ к соответствующему свойству и не меняет стиль заполнения (что в итоге работает, но это неправильно во всех смыслах). Мой косяк.

```js
const PATHS = ['M327.5 68.43c16.24,16.28 26.29,38.75 26.29,63.57l-60 0c0,-8.29 -3.36,-15.78 -8.79,-21.21l42.43 -42.43 0.07 0.07zm-28.71 43.8c0,-1.6 0.39,-3.15 1.18,-4.64 0.78,-1.5 1.9,-2.64 3.34,-3.43 1.44,-0.79 3.05,-1.19 4.83,-1.19 2.75,0 5,0.9 6.76,2.68 1.76,1.8 2.63,4.05 2.63,6.79 0,2.75 -0.89,5.03 -2.66,6.85 -1.77,1.8 -4,2.71 -6.69,2.71 -1.67,0 -3.26,-0.38 -4.77,-1.13 -1.51,-0.76 -2.66,-1.86 -3.44,-3.32 -0.79,-1.45 -1.18,-3.23 -1.18,-5.32zm4.94 0.26c0,1.8 0.42,3.19 1.28,4.14 0.85,0.97 1.91,1.45 3.16,1.45 1.25,0 2.3,-0.48 3.15,-1.45 0.85,-0.95 1.27,-2.35 1.27,-4.18 0,-1.78 -0.42,-3.15 -1.27,-4.11 -0.85,-0.96 -1.9,-1.44 -3.15,-1.44 -1.25,0 -2.31,0.48 -3.16,1.44 -0.86,0.96 -1.28,2.34 -1.28,4.15zm15.47 -9.13l2.67 0 0 -1.37c0,-1.53 0.16,-2.68 0.49,-3.43 0.32,-0.76 0.92,-1.37 1.79,-1.85 0.88,-0.47 1.98,-0.71 3.31,-0.71 1.37,0 2.71,0.21 4.02,0.61l-0.64 3.34c-0.77,-0.18 -1.5,-0.27 -2.21,-0.27 -0.7,0 -1.2,0.16 -1.5,0.49 -0.31,0.33 -0.45,0.96 -0.45,1.89l0 1.3 6 0 0 -1.37c0,-1.53 0.16,-2.68 0.49,-3.43 0.32,-0.76 0.92,-1.37 1.79,-1.85 0.87,-0.47 1.98,-0.71 3.32,-0.71 1.36,0 2.71,0.21 4.01,0.61l-0.65 3.34c-0.76,-0.18 -1.5,-0.27 -2.2,-0.27 -0.7,0 -1.19,0.16 -1.5,0.49 -0.3,0.33 -0.45,0.96 -0.45,1.89l0 1.3 3.59 0 0 3.78 -3.59 0 0 14.4 -4.81 0 0 -14.4 -6 0 0 14.4 -4.81 0 0 -14.4 -2.67 0 0 -3.78z',
'M263.88 42c23.01,0.02 46,8.81 63.55,26.36l-42.43 42.43c-5.86,-5.86 -13.54,-8.79 -21.21,-8.79l0 -60 0.09 0zm11.79 50l0 -32 21.59 0 0 3.75 -17.34 0 0 9.97 15.01 0 0 3.75 -15.01 0 0 14.53 -4.25 0z'];

const EVENTS = {'mousedown' : 'rgb(120,120,255)', 'mousemove' : 'rgb(255,60,60)'};

let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
let element_detector = document.createElement('canvas');
let w = menu.width = element_detector.width = 600;
let h = menu.height = element_detector.height = 200;
let ctx = menu.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(120,120,120)';


let ctx_d = element_detector.getContext('2d');
ctx_d.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
ctx_d.fill(new Path2D(PATHS[0]));
ctx_d.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,255,0)';
ctx_d.fill(new Path2D(PATHS[1]));

menu.addEventListener('mousedown', detectElement);
menu.addEventListener('mousemove', detectElement);
menu.addEventListener('mouseup', detectElement);


function drawMenu(menu_item=-1, event=''){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
  PATHS.forEach((path, index) => {
      ctx.save();
      if(index == menu_item && event){
          ctx.fillStyle = EVENTS[event];        
      }
      ctx.fill(new Path2D(path), 'evenodd');
      ctx.restore();
  })
}

drawMenu();

function detectElement(event){
    let x = event.offsetX;
    let y = event.offsetY;
    let data = ctx_d.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    if(data[0] == 0 && data[1] == 255){
        drawMenu(1, event.type);
    } else if (data[0] == 255 && data[1] == 0){
        drawMenu(0, event.type);
    } else {
        drawMenu();
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="menu"></canvas>
```

Добавляю измененный код. Здесь отрисовка на "теневом холсте" производится перебором PATHS с назначением цвета в красном канале согласно индексу в массиве: `(index + 1)*10`. Единица добавляется чтобы оставить 0 для пустоты вокруг, а кратно десяти чтобы был разрыв между смежными фигурами. Похоже, что `anti-aliasing` по границам фигур создает смещение по цвету и точность обнаружения нарушается. А так достаточно точно.

```
    PATHS.forEach((path, index) => {
        ctx_d.fillStyle = `rgb(${(index + 1)*10},0,0)`;
        ctx_d.fill(new Path2D(path));
    })
```

В функцию `drawMenu()` добавил подсветку белым вырезанных в сегментах иконках. Так они представляют из себя отверстия, при наведении под это отверстие подкладывается белый сегмент без отверстия (благодаря `fill-rull: nonzero`). Для события mouseup это опция отменена так как по сути это возвращение к дефолтному отображению.

```
    if(event !== 'mouseup'){
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fill(new Path2D(path), 'nonzero');
    }
```

Функция `detectElement()` упростилась, мы просто получаем индекс пути в массиве `PATHS` обратным преобразованием. При этом `0` значение красного канала, соответствующее фону вокруг, преобразуется в `-1`.

```
    function detectElement(event){
        let x = event.offsetX;
        let y = event.offsetY;
        let index = ctx_d.getImageData(x-1, y-1, 1, 1).data[0]/10 - 1;
        drawMenu(index, event.type);
    }
```

PS. Какой то баг с сегментом с крестиком, никак не работает на нем правильно nonzero и белый фон под вырезом отсутствует. Это где-то на уровне формирования векторных путей, в коде все нормально, скорее всего...)

```js
    const PATHS = [
    "M331.06 175.45l-9.55 -27.39c-3.6,1.26 -7.48,1.94 -11.51,1.94 -9.3,0 -17.75,-3.63 -24.02,-9.55l-19.9 21.09c11.46,10.82 26.91,17.46 43.92,17.46 7.38,0 14.46,-1.25 21.06,-3.55zm-35.5 -12.81c-0.4,0.6 -1.1,1.4 0.87,3.84 0.93,1.15 2.34,1.55 3.83,1.55 1.49,0 2.78,-0.52 3.84,-1.55 1.05,-1.04 1.59,-2.3 1.59,-3.77 0,-1.47 -0.54,-2.72 -1.59,-3.76 -1.06,-1.04 -2.34,-1.56 -3.84,-1.56 -0.78,0 -1.53,0.16 -2.23,0.48l-0.57 -1.29c-4.14,0.71 -7.17,2.75 -9.08,6.11 0.55,0.98 1.22,1.86 2,2.63 1.9,1.84 4.23,3 7.01,3.48 -1.2,-0.53 -2.16,-1.34 -2.89,-2.43 -0.73,-1.11 -1.1,-2.32 -1.1,-3.66 0,-0.81 0.14,-1.6 0.43,-2.37 2.39,0.75 2.05,0.93 2.43,1.3 0.9,-1.6 1.99,0.5 4.34,1.54l-1.98 -4.15c1.6,-0.71 3.3,-0.37 4.53,0.84 0.8,0.78 1.2,1.73 1.2,2.84 0,1.1 -0.4,2.05 -1.2,2.84 -0.8,0.79 -1.76,1.18 -2.89,1.18 -1.13,0 -2.1,-0.39 -2.9,-1.18 -0.79,-0.79 -0.82,-2.46 -1.8,-2.91zm16.59 0.05c-0.56,-0.98 -1.23,-1.86 -2.03,-2.63 -1.91,-1.85 -4.26,-3.01 -7.07,-3.48 1.22,0.53 2.2,1.33 2.95,2.42 0.75,1.12 1.13,2.35 1.13,3.7 0,1.34 -0.37,2.55 -1.11,3.65 -0.74,1.1 -1.7,1.91 -2.91,2.45 4.13,-0.71 7.14,-2.75 9.04,-6.11z",
    "M364.38 81.24c6.09,9.8 9.62,21.37 9.62,33.76 0,7.84 -1.41,15.36 -4,22.3l-27.19 -10.1c1.42,-3.8 2.19,-7.91 2.19,-12.2 0,-6.78 -1.93,-13.1 -5.26,-18.46l24.64 -15.3zm2.56 26.51l-1.28 0 0 -2.29c0,-0.39 -0.08,-0.67 -0.22,-0.83 -0.15,-0.16 -0.42,-0.24 -0.82,-0.24l-4.01 0 0 1.44 -1.93 -1.93 1.93 -2.2 0 1.41 4.44 0c0.54,0 0.99,0.18 1.35,0.54 0.36,0.37 0.54,0.82 0.54,1.38l0 2.72zm1.48 2.1l-1.42 0 0 3.74c0,0.55 -0.17,1.01 -0.53,1.37 -0.36,0.36 -0.82,0.54 -1.37,0.54l-5.13 0 0 -1.29 4.67 0c0.4,0 0.68,-0.07 0.84,-0.22 0.16,-0.14 0.24,-0.42 0.24,-0.83l0 -3.31 -1.45 0 1.94 -1.93 2.21 1.93zm-9.97 -5.31l-4.66 0c-0.4,0 -0.69,0.08 -0.85,0.22 -0.16,0.15 -0.24,0.42 -0.24,0.83l0 2.14 1.47 0 -2.16 1.95 -2.01 -1.95 1.41 0 0 -2.57c0,-0.55 0.18,-1 0.55,-1.36 0.36,-0.36 0.82,-0.54 1.37,-0.54l5.12 0 0 1.28zm1.2 10.37l-1.93 2 0 -1.41 -4.41 0c-0.55,0 -1,-0.19 -1.36,-0.55 -0.36,-0.36 -0.54,-0.82 -0.54,-1.36l0 -3.74 1.29 0 0 3.3c0,0.4 0.07,0.67 0.22,0.83 0.15,0.15 0.42,0.23 0.81,0.23l3.99 0 0 -1.43 1.93 2.13z",
    "M310 51c22.95,0 43.08,12.09 54.38,30.24l-24.64 15.3c-6.18,-9.93 -17.19,-16.54 -29.74,-16.54l0 -29zm37.1 20.68l-10.22 2.41 -2.56 10.31 -2.41 -10.25 -10.31 -2.53 10.25 -2.41 2.53 -10.31 2.44 10.25 10.28 2.53zm-10.88 -2.41l-1.75 -7.84 0 9.66 1.75 -1.82zm8.47 2.44l-9.66 0 1.82 1.78 7.84 -1.78zm-11.02 -0.12l-1.82 -1.78 -7.84 1.78 9.66 0zm0.59 10.29l0 -9.67 -1.78 1.82 1.78 7.85z",
    "M266.08 161.54c-12.36,-11.67 -20.08,-28.2 -20.08,-46.54l29 0c0,10.03 4.22,19.07 10.98,25.45l-19.9 21.09zm4.96 -30.32l-0.36 0.5c-1.25,-0.13 -2.59,-0.29 -4.03,-0.5 -0.02,-0.01 -0.03,-0.02 -0.04,-0.03 0,-0.04 0.18,-0.11 0.54,-0.19l3.89 0.22zm9.46 5.4c-0.66,0.64 -1.11,0.96 -1.36,0.95 -0.58,-0.04 -5.14,-0.2 -13.67,-0.5 -0.4,0.14 -0.79,0.26 -1.16,0.36 -0.89,0.24 -1.68,0.36 -2.34,0.37 -1.93,0.02 -3.35,-0.24 -4.26,-0.78 0.71,0.01 1.12,-0.13 1.21,-0.42 0.04,-0.07 0.05,-0.15 0.05,-0.23 0,-0.49 -0.34,-0.83 -1.03,-0.99 -0.66,-0.14 -1.1,0 -1.31,0.44 -0.12,0.24 -0.11,0.44 0.05,0.6 -0.14,-0.07 -0.27,-0.25 -0.42,-0.57 -0.06,-0.74 1.17,-1.54 3.7,-2.39 0.95,-1.28 1.95,-1.9 3.01,-1.84 1.12,0.06 2.52,0.22 4.19,0.46 1.35,0.21 2.39,0.3 3.12,0.28 0.31,-0.01 1.27,-1.56 2.9,-4.65 0.29,-0.01 0.51,0 0.67,0.04 0.11,0.03 0.27,0.07 0.47,0.12l-0.76 3.51 4.96 0.51c-0.05,0.08 -0.16,0.17 -0.34,0.27 -0.44,0.01 -2.06,-0.04 -4.87,-0.15l-0.38 1.41c-0.28,0.27 -0.83,0.76 -1.67,1.46 -0.35,0.27 -0.87,0.57 -1.56,0.9l10.8 0.84zm-21.69 -2.92c-0.29,0.1 -0.74,0.29 -1.35,0.57 -0.23,0.14 -0.55,0.37 -0.93,0.7 -1.22,-0.7 -2.8,-1.59 -4.73,-2.65 -0.07,-0.04 -0.1,-0.07 -0.1,-0.1 0,-0.15 0.71,-0.26 2.12,-0.34l4.99 1.82zm-0.33 2.8c0,0.29 -0.43,0.44 -1.27,0.44 -0.37,0 -0.55,-0.12 -0.55,-0.34 0,-0.58 0.35,-0.85 1.05,-0.82 0.51,0.03 0.77,0.27 0.77,0.72zm8.13 -2.31l-0.34 -1.44 -1.24 -0.16 0.58 1.74 1 -0.14zm-1.44 0.22l-0.5 -1.82 -0.19 1.93 0.69 -0.11zm-0.8 -1.9c-0.82,-0.27 -1.52,-0.4 -2.11,-0.4 -0.24,0 -0.44,0.02 -0.6,0.07 -0.34,0.09 -0.81,0.52 -1.4,1.29 0.31,0.01 0.85,0.07 1.62,0.16 0.7,0.15 1.45,0.41 2.25,0.8l0.24 -1.92z",
    "M246 115c0,-17.74 7.22,-33.79 18.88,-45.39l20.45 20.57c-6.38,6.34 -10.33,15.12 -10.33,24.82l-29 0zm27.57 -21.81c0,2.47 -1.55,4.99 -4.64,7.56 -2.16,1.78 -4.83,3.43 -8.02,4.95 0.11,-0.61 0.17,-1.19 0.17,-1.75 0,-1.43 -0.45,-2.74 -1.36,-3.91 -0.85,-0.94 -1.7,-1.88 -2.56,-2.81 -0.91,-1.14 -1.36,-2.39 -1.36,-3.75 0,-1.33 0.45,-2.43 1.35,-3.29 0.9,-0.86 2.02,-1.29 3.36,-1.29 0.92,0 1.77,0.24 2.56,0.72 0.86,0.52 1.4,1.21 1.63,2.05 0.95,-1.85 2.34,-2.77 4.17,-2.77 1.24,0 2.32,0.4 3.24,1.2 0.98,0.85 1.46,1.87 1.46,3.09z",
    "M310 84c17.12,0 31,13.88 31,31 0,17.12 -13.88,31 -31,31 -17.12,0 -31,-13.88 -31,-31 0,-17.12 13.88,-31 31,-31zm17.95 46.01l-3.52 0c0,-1.75 -1.77,-3.05 -5.31,-3.88 -1.72,-0.41 -5.01,-0.83 -9.84,-1.26 -3.54,-0.31 -5.31,-0.71 -5.31,-1.23 0,-1.01 2.46,-1.73 7.39,-2.18l-3.89 0c-5.49,0.44 -8.24,1.22 -8.24,2.36 0,0.99 1.18,1.72 3.53,2.19 2.18,0.38 4.36,0.77 6.55,1.16 2.35,0.61 3.53,1.55 3.53,2.84l-20.79 0 0 -16.7 2.51 0 0 -2.5 -0.64 0.53 -1.3 -1.87 4.28 -3.26 0 -0.82 -0.58 0.46 -1.15 -1.67 8.08 -6.23 2.41 1.87 0 -1.87 2.19 0 0 3.58 2.13 1.66 2.43 -1.87 1.02 0.81 5.11 -3.89 2.7 2.1 0 -2.1 2.44 0 0 3.99 3.73 2.9 -1.3 1.87 -0.64 -0.51 0 6.82 2.48 0 0 16.7zm-1.22 -24.84l-3.45 -2.71 0 -3.86 -1.68 0 0 2.53 -3.06 -2.39 -4.78 3.64 2.02 1.52 0 -2.58 3.02 0 0 4.92 2.28 1.76 2.45 0 0 3.81 -1.49 0 -0.22 0.32 -0.77 -0.63 0 2.86 3.96 0 0 -8.94 0.98 0.82 0.74 -1.07zm-4.13 4.71l-4.31 -3.34 0 -4.79 -2.08 0 0 3.16 -3.8 -2.94 -10.2 7.88 0.91 1.31 1.24 -1.01 0 11.1 3.09 0 0 -7.86 3.84 0 0 7.86 9.16 0 0 -11.07 1.24 1.02 0.91 -1.32zm-12.93 -6.46l-2.18 -1.67 0 -3.48 -1.51 0 0 2.32 -2.73 -2.16 -7.47 5.77 0.65 0.97 0.9 -0.76 0 1.46 4.23 -3.25 2.7 2.08 0 -2.08 2.44 0 0 3.1 2.97 -2.3zm-3.37 2.6l0 -3.04 -1.69 0 0 2.55 -3.05 -2.41 -8.25 6.39 0.71 1.08 1.01 -0.83 0 8.98 2.51 0 0 -6.39 3.13 0 0 6.39 3.08 0 0 -2.59 -1.29 0 0 -3.8 1.29 0 0 -0.88 -0.75 0.62 -1.62 -2.29 4.92 -3.78zm12.35 12.07l-5.06 0 0 -4.7 5.06 0 0 4.7z",
    "M243.03 47.63c17.17,-17.08 40.84,-27.63 66.97,-27.63l0 27c-18.71,0 -35.65,7.55 -47.94,19.78l-19.03 -19.15zm42.28 -1.35l-0.73 0 0 2.42 -2.79 0 0 -2.42 -8.1 0 0 2.42 -2.76 0 0 -2.42 -0.73 0 0 -11.52c0,-1.06 0.62,-1.83 1.86,-2.31 1.2,-0.48 3.1,-0.71 5.69,-0.71 2.6,0 4.49,0.23 5.7,0.71 1.24,0.48 1.86,1.25 1.86,2.31l0 11.52zm-0.78 -6.93l0 -4.6 -6.35 0 0 4.6 6.35 0zm0.02 5.27c0,-0.27 -0.09,-0.5 -0.28,-0.69 -0.19,-0.19 -0.41,-0.28 -0.68,-0.28 -0.26,0 -0.49,0.09 -0.68,0.28 -0.2,0.19 -0.29,0.42 -0.29,0.69 0,0.26 0.09,0.49 0.29,0.68 0.19,0.19 0.42,0.28 0.68,0.28 0.27,0 0.49,-0.09 0.68,-0.28 0.19,-0.19 0.28,-0.42 0.28,-0.68zm-7.23 -5.27l0 -4.6 -6.34 0 0 4.6 6.34 0zm4.47 5l0 -0.57 -8.1 0 0 0.57 8.1 0zm0 1.15l0 -0.56 -8.1 0 0 0.56 8.1 0zm-8.9 -0.88c0,-0.27 -0.1,-0.5 -0.28,-0.69 -0.19,-0.19 -0.42,-0.28 -0.69,-0.28 -0.27,0 -0.5,0.09 -0.69,0.28 -0.18,0.19 -0.28,0.42 -0.28,0.69 0,0.26 0.1,0.49 0.28,0.68 0.19,0.19 0.42,0.28 0.69,0.28 0.27,0 0.5,-0.09 0.69,-0.28 0.18,-0.19 0.28,-0.42 0.28,-0.68z",
    "M215 115c0,-26.33 10.72,-50.16 28.03,-67.37l19.03 19.15c-12.39,12.31 -20.06,29.37 -20.06,48.22l-27 0zm29.14 -36.6l-3.04 1.48 2.79 -1.92 0.25 0.44zm-1.83 -1.73l-1.92 2.29 1.48 -2.55 0.44 0.26zm2.06 4.36l-3.38 -0.25 3.38 -0.27 0 0.52zm-4.93 -4.82l-0.23 2.73 -0.29 -2.73 0.52 0zm1 4.87l-1.43 0 0.2 -1.46 0.95 0 0.28 1.46zm2.84 5.51l-1.63 1.44 0 -0.44 1.18 -1 -0.67 0 0 -3.98 -0.51 0 0 -0.21 1.63 0 0 4.19zm-4.99 -5.88l-1.2 0.37 0 -0.37 1.2 0zm0 -0.2l-1.2 0 0 -0.69 -5.5 0 0 0.69 -1.2 0 0 -2.03 1.2 0 0 0.63 5.5 0 0 -0.63 1.2 0 0 2.03zm-1.43 0l-5.04 0 0 -0.49 5.04 0 0 0.49zm0 0.57l-5.04 0 0 -0.37 5.04 0 0 0.37zm-7.07 -4.87l-0.29 2.73 -0.23 -2.73 0.52 0zm1.96 4.87l-1.36 -0.37 1.2 0 0.16 0.37zm-3.45 -2.12l-1.89 -2.29 0.43 -0.26 1.46 2.55zm1.37 2.12l-1.43 0 0.29 -1.46 0.94 0 0.2 1.46zm-2.06 -1.2l-3.04 -1.48 0.25 -0.44 2.79 1.92zm0.08 0.9l-3.35 0.25 0 -0.52 3.35 0.27zm14.19 13.54l-0.41 0 0 0.6 -0.65 0 0 2.21 -2.53 0 0 -1.46c-0.49,-0.01 -0.78,-0.26 -0.85,-0.75l-6.19 0c-0.07,0.49 -0.34,0.74 -0.83,0.75l0 1.46 -2.52 0 0 -2.21 -0.66 0 0 -0.6 -0.41 0 0 -0.86 0.41 0 -0.02 -11.23c0,-0.23 0.12,-0.44 0.34,-0.65 0.19,-0.19 0.38,-0.3 0.56,-0.3l12.46 0c0.18,0 0.38,0.11 0.59,0.31 0.2,0.2 0.3,0.41 0.3,0.64l0 11.23 0.41 0 0 0.86zm-14.83 -6.29l-1.62 -1.44 0 -4.19 1.62 0 0 0.21 -0.5 0 0 3.98 -0.66 0 1.16 1 0 0.44zm13.94 -1.44l0 -4.19 -6.19 0 0 4.19 6.19 0zm0.08 6.58l0 -1.6 -2.23 0 0 1.6 2.23 0zm-7.19 -6.58l0 -4.19 -6.19 0 0 4.19 6.19 0zm5.13 8.24c0,-0.48 -0.23,-0.71 -0.69,-0.71 -0.47,0 -0.71,0.23 -0.71,0.71 0,0.46 0.24,0.69 0.71,0.69 0.46,0 0.69,-0.23 0.69,-0.69zm-0.72 -2.74l0 -0.55 -7.87 0 0 0.55 7.87 0zm0 1.08l0 -0.54 -7.87 0 0 0.54 7.87 0zm3.44 1.04l0 -0.58 -14.75 0 0 0.58 2.76 0c0.17,-0.2 0.39,-0.29 0.64,-0.29 0.25,0 0.46,0.09 0.64,0.29l6.64 0c0.17,-0.2 0.39,-0.29 0.65,-0.29 0.25,0 0.46,0.09 0.64,0.29l2.78 0zm-11.86 -1.04l0 -1.6 -2.23 0 0 1.6 2.23 0zm1.23 1.66c0,-0.48 -0.23,-0.71 -0.7,-0.71 -0.47,0 -0.7,0.23 -0.7,0.71 0,0.46 0.23,0.69 0.7,0.69 0.47,0 0.7,-0.23 0.7,-0.69z",
    "M215 115l27 0c0,19.49 8.2,37.05 21.33,49.45l-18.53 19.64c-18.35,-17.32 -29.8,-41.87 -29.8,-69.09zm19.42 23.29l-1.54 0 0.3 -1.43 1 0 0.24 1.43zm9.68 12.76l-0.54 0 0 -0.98c0,-0.75 -0.25,-1.39 -0.76,-1.93 -0.51,-0.53 -1.12,-0.8 -1.84,-0.8 -0.71,0 -1.32,0.27 -1.83,0.8 -0.51,0.54 -0.76,1.18 -0.76,1.93l-0.01 0.98 -7.05 0 0 -12.51 12.79 0 0 12.51zm-0.96 -0.85c0,0.62 -0.21,1.15 -0.63,1.59 -0.42,0.44 -0.93,0.66 -1.51,0.66 -0.6,0 -1.1,-0.22 -1.52,-0.66 -0.42,-0.44 -0.63,-0.97 -0.63,-1.59 0,-0.62 0.21,-1.15 0.63,-1.59 0.42,-0.44 0.92,-0.66 1.52,-0.66 0.58,0 1.09,0.22 1.51,0.66 0.42,0.44 0.63,0.97 0.63,1.59zm-12.22 -1.49c-0.49,-0.91 -1.2,-1.37 -2.15,-1.37 -0.71,0 -1.32,0.27 -1.83,0.8 -0.51,0.54 -0.76,1.18 -0.76,1.93l0 0.98 -1.14 0 0 -6.02c0,-0.62 0.4,-0.93 1.21,-0.93l0.44 0 1.16 -2.8c0.15,-0.37 0.44,-0.56 0.85,-0.56l2.22 0 0 7.97zm0 1.49c0,0.62 -0.21,1.15 -0.63,1.59 -0.42,0.44 -0.92,0.66 -1.52,0.66 -0.59,0 -1.1,-0.22 -1.52,-0.66 -0.42,-0.44 -0.63,-0.97 -0.63,-1.59 0,-0.62 0.21,-1.15 0.63,-1.59 0.42,-0.44 0.93,-0.66 1.52,-0.66 0.6,0 1.1,0.22 1.52,0.66 0.42,0.44 0.63,0.97 0.63,1.59zm10.85 -5.19l0 -3.27 -2.31 0 0 -2.31 -3.27 0 0 2.31 -2.31 0 0 3.27 2.31 0 0 2.31 3.27 0 0 -2.31 2.31 0zm-11.23 -0.91l0 -2.76 -2.33 0 -1.05 2.76 3.38 0z",
    "M264.88 69.61c6.82,6.86 13.63,13.71 20.45,20.57 10.05,-9.5 19.75,-10 24.67,-10.18 0,-9.67 0,-19.33 0,-29 -15.52,-0.02 -32.42,5.78 -45.12,18.61zm33.81 6.76l-1.9 0 -4.73 -4.7 -4.7 4.7 -1.97 0 0 -1.91 4.73 -4.73 -4.73 -4.7 0 -1.96 1.97 0 4.72 4.71 4.71 -4.71 1.9 0 0 1.96 -4.68 4.68 4.68 4.69 0 1.97z",
    "M331.06 175.45l-9.55 -27.39c9.84,-3.43 17.68,-11.12 21.3,-20.86l27.19 10.1c-6.62,17.82 -20.95,31.89 -38.94,38.15zm25.94 -31.9c-0.03,0.58 -0.38,0.93 -1.04,1.08 -0.09,-0.59 -0.41,-0.88 -0.98,-0.88 -0.38,0 -0.99,0.22 -1.85,0.65 -0.93,0.45 -1.39,0.84 -1.39,1.16 0,0.15 0.02,0.37 0.08,0.67 0.05,0.29 0.07,0.51 0.07,0.66 0,0.55 -0.2,0.97 -0.61,1.25 -0.12,-0.2 -0.56,-1.08 -1.32,-2.62 -0.53,-1.07 -1.07,-1.88 -1.6,-2.42 0.16,-0.07 0.32,-0.1 0.48,-0.1 0.26,0 0.6,0.12 1.01,0.36 0.41,0.24 0.71,0.36 0.9,0.36 0.52,0 1.24,-0.2 2.17,-0.59 0.93,-0.4 1.6,-0.6 2.02,-0.6 1.01,0 1.69,0.34 2.06,1.02zm-5.54 6.06c0,0.82 -0.45,1.49 -1.35,1.99 -0.79,0.44 -1.82,0.84 -3.11,1.19 -1.07,0.31 -2.15,0.6 -3.22,0.89 -1.63,0.53 -3.25,1.06 -4.88,1.59 -2.28,0.69 -3.88,1.03 -4.78,1.03 -0.43,0 -0.73,-0.09 -0.89,-0.26 -0.15,-0.17 -0.23,-0.47 -0.23,-0.91 0,-0.08 0.22,-0.26 0.67,-0.54 0.59,-0.38 1.28,-0.93 2.06,-1.67 1.22,-1.15 1.87,-1.76 1.96,-1.84 1.06,-0.91 1.99,-1.86 2.79,-2.85 0.88,-1.2 1.78,-2.4 2.67,-3.6 1.28,-1.51 2.45,-2.27 3.49,-2.27 0.64,0 1.32,0.48 2.04,1.44 0.5,0.68 0.94,1.46 1.31,2.33 0.3,0.57 0.6,1.14 0.91,1.7 0.38,0.72 0.56,1.31 0.56,1.78zm-5.24 -6.41c-0.02,0.25 -0.2,0.67 -0.54,1.24 -0.24,0.42 -1.21,1.42 -2.91,3.01 -2.06,1.87 -3.18,2.91 -3.36,3.12l0.21 0.25 3.61 -3.25c1.82,-1.56 3.11,-2.34 3.88,-2.34 0.1,0 0.2,0.01 0.3,0.04 -0.48,-0.35 -0.88,-1.04 -1.19,-2.07zm7.49 -0.05c-1.5,0.73 -2.44,1.09 -2.84,1.09 -0.18,0 -0.61,-0.13 -1.31,-0.41l0.73 1.08 3.42 -1.76zm3.09 0.5c-0.12,-0.17 -0.25,-0.25 -0.38,-0.25 -0.26,0 -0.38,0.19 -0.38,0.59 0,0.11 0.01,0.19 0.04,0.27 0.33,-0.05 0.57,-0.25 0.72,-0.61z",

    ]

    const EVENTS = {
        'mousedown' : 'rgba(120,120,255,0.8)',
        'mousemove' : 'rgb(255,60,60,1)',
        'mouseup' : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)'
    }

    let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    let element_detector = document.createElement('canvas');
    let w = menu.width = element_detector.width = 600;
    let h = menu.height = element_detector.height = 200;
    let ctx = menu.getContext('2d');
    let ctx_d = element_detector.getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle = EVENTS.mouseup;

    PATHS.forEach((path, index) => {
        ctx_d.fillStyle = `rgb(${(index + 1)*10},0,0)`;
        ctx_d.fill(new Path2D(path));
    })

    menu.addEventListener('mousedown', detectElement);
    menu.addEventListener('mousemove', detectElement);
    menu.addEventListener('mouseup', detectElement);

    drawMenu();

    function drawMenu(menu_item=-1, event=''){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
        PATHS.forEach((path, index) => {
            ctx.save();
            if(index == menu_item && event){
                if(event !== 'mouseup'){
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
                    ctx.fill(new Path2D(path), 'nonzero');
                }
                ctx.fillStyle = EVENTS[event];
            }
            ctx.fill(new Path2D(path), 'evenodd');
            ctx.restore();
        })
    }

    function detectElement(event){
        let x = event.offsetX;
        let y = event.offsetY;
        let index = ctx_d.getImageData(x-1, y-1, 1, 1).data[0]/10 - 1;
        drawMenu(index, event.type);
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/city-tornado-doomsday-scene-illustration_456031-22.jpg" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0">
<canvas id="menu" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/962780/188366

Comment: Я по смыслу помню, спасибо. Надо было вроде `ctx_d.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data - 1` прописывать для более понятного результата?

Answer (score 3):

> Нужна верстка круга с пустотой внутри и элементами вокруг данного
> круга. С ними в будущем нужно будет взаимодействовать

Другими словами это будет радиальное меню со ссылками.

Самый простой путь, - это создать сегменты на круге с помощью `path` SVG и привязать к каждому сегменту свои ссылки. Я добавил ещё тултипы, чтобы при наведении менялся не только цвет, но и всплывала подсказка.

```
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions"> 
    <title> Все вопросы </title>
  <path class="segment"  id="s1"  d="M 55 55 L 105 55 A 50 50 0 0 1 90.35 90.35 Z"/>
</a>
```

Все ссылки рабочие в пределах RuSO, пощелкайте ради интереса.

Чтобы внести немного разнообразия, я сделал двухцветное выделение разных секторов.

При необходимости можно сделать :hover одноцветным.

Прорезь вокруг центрального круга реализована с помощью маски SVG

```
<defs>
  <mask id="msk">  
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <circle fill="white" stroke-width="3" stroke="red" cx='55' cy='55' r='24'  />  
  </mask>
</defs>
```

```css
.back {
position:relative;
}
svg {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  
  position:absolute;
  top:30%;
  left:30%;
 
  --d:red;
  --r:greenYellow;
  --g:yellowgreen;
}

.segment {
fill:#2F3031;
opacity:0.8;
stroke:#fff;
stroke-opacity:0.3;
}


#center {
fill:#2F3031;

stroke-width:3;
stroke:white;
cursor: pointer; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;

} 
#center:hover {
fill: var(--g);

}

#s1,#s3, #s5, #s7 {
cursor: pointer; 
 -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

#s2,#s4,#s6,#s8 {
cursor: pointer; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}


#s1:hover, #s3:hover, #s5:hover, #s7:hover  {
 fill: var(--d);
 
}
#s2:hover, #s4:hover, #s6:hover, #s8:hover  {
 fill: var(--r);
 
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Foro_Romano.jpg/1200px-Foro_Romano.jpg" />
</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox='0 0 110 110'> 
<defs>
  <mask id="msk">  
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <circle fill="white" stroke-width="3" stroke="red" cx='55' cy='55' r='24'  />  
  </mask>
</defs>  
  
  <!-- Сегменты круга с рабочими ссылками -->
<g transform="rotate(-22.5 55 55)" mask="url(#msk)" >
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions"> 
    <title> Все вопросы </title>
  <path class="segment"  id="s1"  d="M 55 55 L 105 55 A 50 50 0 0 1 90.35 90.35 Z"/>
</a>
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript"> 
        <title> Все вопросы [javascript]  </title>
      <path class="segment" id="s2"  d="M 55 55 L 90.35 90.35 A 50 50 0 0 1 55 105 Z"/>
     </a> 
    
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg">
    <title> Все вопросы [SVG]  </title>
<path class="segment" id="s3"  d="M 55 55 L 55 105 A 50 50 0 0 1 19.6447 90.35 Z" />
</a>
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css"> 
       <title> Все вопросы [CSS]  </title>
    <path class="segment" id="s4"  d="M 55 55 L 19.64 90.353 A 50 50 0 0 1 5 55 Z" />
    </a>
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java"> 
     <title> Все вопросы [java] </title>
<path class="segment" id="s5"  d="M 55 55 L 5 55 A 50 50 0 0 1 19.64 19.64 Z" />
</a> 
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python">
       <title> Все вопросы python  </title>
    <path class="segment" id="s6"  d="M 55 55 L 19.64 19.64 A 50 50 0 0 1 55 5 Z" />
    </a> 
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help"> 
     <title> Справочный центр </title> 
<path class="segment" id="s7"  d="M 55 55 L 55 5 A 50 50 0 0 1 90.35 19.64 Z" />
</a>
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php"> 
        <title> Все вопросы [php]   </title>
    <path class="segment" id="s8"  d="M 55 55 L 90.35 19.64 A 50 50 0 0 1 105 55 Z" />
    
    </a>
</g>  
      <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html"> 
        <title> Все вопросы [HTML]  </title> 
     
  <circle mask="url(#msk)" id="center" cx='55' cy='55' r='24'  />  
   </a>
 </svg>
```

Comment: @Leonid  сегменты полупрозрачные, разверни на весь экран

Comment: Да, точно, так намного круче. И еще с задержкой анимации! Буду изучать код.

Comment: @Leonid в комментариях, что-то объяснить довольно сложно из-за краткости Вот по маскам я писал подробный ответ  Это довольно сложный вопрос, но намного эффективней работает чем `clip-path` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/919186/28748 Прочтешь, станет понятно / `<g>` групповой тег и в него можно добавлять несколько разнородных команд. transform="rotate" Это я немного повернул сектор для центровки. Маска другая команда, которая применяется для все элементов входящих в группу.

Comment: @Leonid Спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 2):

### Вариант с однотонными секторами и иконками

```css
.back {
position:relative;
}
svg {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  
  position:absolute;
  top:30%;
  left:10%;
 
}

.segment {
fill:#2F3031;
opacity:0.8;
stroke:#fff;
stroke-opacity:0.3;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;

}

.segment:hover {
fill:red;
opacity:0.8;
}


#center {
fill:#2F3031;
stroke-width:3;
stroke:white;
cursor: pointer; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
} 
#center:hover {
fill:red;
}

.icon {
fill:#75726F;
pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXqwh.jpg" />
</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox='0 0 110 110'> 
<defs>
   <mask id="msk">  
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <circle fill="white" stroke-width="3" stroke="red" cx='55' cy='55' r='24'  />  
  </mask>
</defs>  
  
  <!-- Сегменты круга с рабочими ссылками -->
<g transform="rotate(-22.5 55 55)" mask="url(#msk)" >
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions"> 
    <title> Все вопросы </title>
  <path class="segment"  id="s1"  d="M 55 55 L 105 55 A 50 50 0 0 1 90.35 90.35 Z"/>
</a>
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript"> 
        <title> Все вопросы [javascript]  </title>
      <path class="segment" id="s2"  d="M 55 55 L 90.35 90.35 A 50 50 0 0 1 55 105 Z"/>
     </a> 
    
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg">
    <title> Все вопросы [SVG]  </title>
<path class="segment" id="s3"  d="M 55 55 L 55 105 A 50 50 0 0 1 19.6447 90.35 Z" />
</a>
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css"> 
       <title> Все вопросы [CSS]  </title>
    <path class="segment" id="s4"  d="M 55 55 L 19.64 90.353 A 50 50 0 0 1 5 55 Z" />
    </a>
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java"> 
     <title> Все вопросы [java] </title>
<path class="segment" id="s5"  d="M 55 55 L 5 55 A 50 50 0 0 1 19.64 19.64 Z" />
</a> 
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python">
       <title> Все вопросы python  </title>
    <path class="segment" id="s6"  d="M 55 55 L 19.64 19.64 A 50 50 0 0 1 55 5 Z" />
    </a> 
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help"> 
     <title> Справочный центр </title> 
<path class="segment" id="s7"  d="M 55 55 L 55 5 A 50 50 0 0 1 90.35 19.64 Z" />
</a>
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php"> 
        <title> Все вопросы [php]   </title>
    <path class="segment" id="s8"  d="M 55 55 L 90.35 19.64 A 50 50 0 0 1 105 55 Z" />
    
    </a>
</g>  
      <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html"> 
        <title> Все вопросы [HTML]  </title> 
     
  <circle mask="url(#msk)"  id="center" cx='55' cy='55' r='24'  />  
  </a>  
         <!-- Иконки -->
    <g transform=" scale(1) translate(45 7)">
    <path class="icon" id="House" d="M15,8.29V5h-2v1.57L10,4l-7,6h2v6h4v-4h2v4h4v-6h2L15,8.29z M9,9c0-0.55,0.45-1,1-1c0.55,0,1,0.45,1,1H9z"/>
    </g>
    
    <g transform=" scale(0.6) translate(125 33)">
    <path class="icon" id="cloud"   d="M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4 9.11 4 6.6 5.64 5.35 8.04 2.34 8.36 0 10.91 0 14c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6h13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5 0-2.64-2.05-4.78-4.65-4.96zM10 17l-3.5-3.5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17 15.18 9l1.41 1.41L10 17z"/>
    </g>
    
    <g transform=" scale(0.6) translate(145 80)">
      <path class="icon" id="podcast" d="M14,12c0,0.74-0.4,1.38-1,1.72V22h-2v-8.28c-0.6-0.35-1-0.98-1-1.72c0-1.1,0.9-2,2-2S14,10.9,14,12z M12,6 c-3.31,0-6,2.69-6,6c0,1.74,0.75,3.31,1.94,4.4l1.42-1.42C8.53,14.25,8,13.19,8,12c0-2.21,1.79-4,4-4s4,1.79,4,4 c0,1.19-0.53,2.25-1.36,2.98l1.42,1.42C17.25,15.31,18,13.74,18,12C18,8.69,15.31,6,12,6z M12,2C6.48,2,2,6.48,2,12 c0,2.85,1.2,5.41,3.11,7.24l1.42-1.42C4.98,16.36,4,14.29,4,12c0-4.41,3.59-8,8-8s8,3.59,8,8c0,2.29-0.98,4.36-2.53,5.82l1.42,1.42 C20.8,17.41,22,14.85,22,12C22,6.48,17.52,2,12,2z"/>
     </g>
     <g transform=" scale(0.6) translate(125 125)">
      <path class="icon" id="task" d="M14,2H6C4.9,2,4.01,2.9,4.01,4L4,20c0,1.1,0.89,2,1.99,2H18c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V8L14,2z M10.94,18L7.4,14.46l1.41-1.41 l2.12,2.12l4.24-4.24l1.41,1.41L10.94,18z M13,9V3.5L18.5,9H13z"/>
     </g>
       <g transform=" scale(0.6) translate(83 145)">
        <path  class="icon" id="video" d="M21 3H3c-1.11 0-2 .89-2 2v12c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h5v2h8v-2h5c1.1 0 1.99-.9 1.99-2L23 5c0-1.11-.9-2-2-2zm0 14H3V5h18v12zm-5-6l-7 4V7z"/>
       </g>
<g transform=" scale(0.6) translate(33 125)">   
     <path class="icon" id="phone"  d="M20 15.5c-1.25 0-2.45-.2-3.57-.57-.35-.11-.74-.03-1.02.24l-2.2 2.2c-2.83-1.44-5.15-3.75-6.59-6.59l2.2-2.21c.28-.26.36-.65.25-1C8.7 6.45 8.5 5.25 8.5 4c0-.55-.45-1-1-1H4c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1 0 9.39 7.61 17 17 17 .55 0 1-.45 1-1v-3.5c0-.55-.45-1-1-1zM19 12h2c0-4.97-4.03-9-9-9v2c3.87 0 7 3.13 7 7zm-4 0h2c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5v2c1.66 0 3 1.34 3 3z"/>  
</g>  
      <g transform=" scale(0.6) translate(18 80)"> 
        <path class="icon" id="comment" d="M20 2H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14l4 4V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm-2 12H6v-2h12v2zm0-3H6V9h12v2zm0-3H6V6h12v2z"/>
      </g>      
<g transform=" scale(0.6) translate(35 40)"> 
    <path class="icon" id="link" d="M3.9 12c0-1.71 1.39-3.1 3.1-3.1h4V7H7c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5s2.24 5 5 5h4v-1.9H7c-1.71 0-3.1-1.39-3.1-3.1zM8 13h8v-2H8v2zm9-6h-4v1.9h4c1.71 0 3.1 1.39 3.1 3.1s-1.39 3.1-3.1 3.1h-4V17h4c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5s-2.24-5-5-5z"/>
</g>    
 </svg>
```

### Вариант добавления тени при наведении на сектора

Добавляется фильтр SVG:

```
<filter id="drop-shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" height="130%" width="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"/> 
      <feOffset dx="3" dy="3" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
</filter>
```

```css
.back {
position:relative;
}
svg {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  
  position:absolute;
  top:30%;
  left:10%;
 
}

.segment {
fill:#2F3031;
opacity:0.8;
stroke:#fff;
stroke-opacity:0.3;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;

}

.segment:hover {
fill:red;
opacity:0.8;
filter:url(#drop-shadow);
}


#center {
fill:#2F3031;
stroke-width:3;
stroke:white;
cursor: pointer; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
} 
#center:hover {
fill:red;
filter:url(#drop-shadow);
}

.icon {
fill:#75726F;
pointer-events:none;
filter:url(#drop-shadow);
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXqwh.jpg" />
</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox='0 0 110 110'> 
<defs>
   <mask id="msk">  
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <circle fill="white" stroke-width="3" stroke="red" cx='55' cy='55' r='24'  />  
  </mask> 
  
      <!-- Фильтр тени при наведении -->
<filter id="drop-shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" height="180%" width="180%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"/> 
      <feOffset dx="1" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
</filter>
</defs>  
  
  <!-- Сегменты круга с рабочими ссылками -->
<g transform="rotate(-22.5 55 55)" mask="url(#msk)" >
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions"> 
    <title> Все вопросы </title>
  <path class="segment"  id="s1"  d="M 55 55 L 105 55 A 50 50 0 0 1 90.35 90.35 Z"/>
</a>
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript"> 
        <title> Все вопросы [javascript]  </title>
      <path class="segment" id="s2"  d="M 55 55 L 90.35 90.35 A 50 50 0 0 1 55 105 Z"/>
     </a> 
    
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg">
    <title> Все вопросы [SVG]  </title>
<path class="segment" id="s3"  d="M 55 55 L 55 105 A 50 50 0 0 1 19.6447 90.35 Z" />
</a>
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css"> 
       <title> Все вопросы [CSS]  </title>
    <path class="segment" id="s4"  d="M 55 55 L 19.64 90.353 A 50 50 0 0 1 5 55 Z" />
    </a>
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java"> 
     <title> Все вопросы [java] </title>
<path class="segment" id="s5"  d="M 55 55 L 5 55 A 50 50 0 0 1 19.64 19.64 Z" />
</a> 
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python">
       <title> Все вопросы python  </title>
    <path class="segment" id="s6"  d="M 55 55 L 19.64 19.64 A 50 50 0 0 1 55 5 Z" />
    </a> 
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help"> 
     <title> Справочный центр </title> 
<path class="segment" id="s7"  d="M 55 55 L 55 5 A 50 50 0 0 1 90.35 19.64 Z" />
</a>
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php"> 
        <title> Все вопросы [php]   </title>
    <path class="segment" id="s8"  d="M 55 55 L 90.35 19.64 A 50 50 0 0 1 105 55 Z" />
    
    </a>
</g>  
      <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html"> 
        <title> Все вопросы [HTML]  </title> 
     
  <circle mask="url(#msk)"  id="center" cx='55' cy='55' r='24'  />  
  </a>  
         <!-- Иконки -->
    <g transform=" scale(1) translate(45 7)">
    <path class="icon" id="House" d="M15,8.29V5h-2v1.57L10,4l-7,6h2v6h4v-4h2v4h4v-6h2L15,8.29z M9,9c0-0.55,0.45-1,1-1c0.55,0,1,0.45,1,1H9z"/>
    </g>
    
    <g transform=" scale(0.6) translate(125 33)">
    <path class="icon" id="cloud"   d="M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4 9.11 4 6.6 5.64 5.35 8.04 2.34 8.36 0 10.91 0 14c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6h13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5 0-2.64-2.05-4.78-4.65-4.96zM10 17l-3.5-3.5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17 15.18 9l1.41 1.41L10 17z"/>
    </g>
    
    <g transform=" scale(0.6) translate(145 80)">
      <path class="icon" id="podcast" d="M14,12c0,0.74-0.4,1.38-1,1.72V22h-2v-8.28c-0.6-0.35-1-0.98-1-1.72c0-1.1,0.9-2,2-2S14,10.9,14,12z M12,6 c-3.31,0-6,2.69-6,6c0,1.74,0.75,3.31,1.94,4.4l1.42-1.42C8.53,14.25,8,13.19,8,12c0-2.21,1.79-4,4-4s4,1.79,4,4 c0,1.19-0.53,2.25-1.36,2.98l1.42,1.42C17.25,15.31,18,13.74,18,12C18,8.69,15.31,6,12,6z M12,2C6.48,2,2,6.48,2,12 c0,2.85,1.2,5.41,3.11,7.24l1.42-1.42C4.98,16.36,4,14.29,4,12c0-4.41,3.59-8,8-8s8,3.59,8,8c0,2.29-0.98,4.36-2.53,5.82l1.42,1.42 C20.8,17.41,22,14.85,22,12C22,6.48,17.52,2,12,2z"/>
     </g>
     <g transform=" scale(0.6) translate(125 125)">
      <path class="icon" id="task" d="M14,2H6C4.9,2,4.01,2.9,4.01,4L4,20c0,1.1,0.89,2,1.99,2H18c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V8L14,2z M10.94,18L7.4,14.46l1.41-1.41 l2.12,2.12l4.24-4.24l1.41,1.41L10.94,18z M13,9V3.5L18.5,9H13z"/>
     </g>
       <g transform=" scale(0.6) translate(83 145)">
        <path  class="icon" id="video" d="M21 3H3c-1.11 0-2 .89-2 2v12c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h5v2h8v-2h5c1.1 0 1.99-.9 1.99-2L23 5c0-1.11-.9-2-2-2zm0 14H3V5h18v12zm-5-6l-7 4V7z"/>
       </g>
<g transform=" scale(0.6) translate(33 125)">   
     <path class="icon" id="phone"  d="M20 15.5c-1.25 0-2.45-.2-3.57-.57-.35-.11-.74-.03-1.02.24l-2.2 2.2c-2.83-1.44-5.15-3.75-6.59-6.59l2.2-2.21c.28-.26.36-.65.25-1C8.7 6.45 8.5 5.25 8.5 4c0-.55-.45-1-1-1H4c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1 0 9.39 7.61 17 17 17 .55 0 1-.45 1-1v-3.5c0-.55-.45-1-1-1zM19 12h2c0-4.97-4.03-9-9-9v2c3.87 0 7 3.13 7 7zm-4 0h2c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5v2c1.66 0 3 1.34 3 3z"/>  
</g>  
      <g transform=" scale(0.6) translate(18 80)"> 
        <path class="icon" id="comment" d="M20 2H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14l4 4V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm-2 12H6v-2h12v2zm0-3H6V9h12v2zm0-3H6V6h12v2z"/>
      </g>      
<g transform=" scale(0.6) translate(35 40)"> 
    <path class="icon" id="link" d="M3.9 12c0-1.71 1.39-3.1 3.1-3.1h4V7H7c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5s2.24 5 5 5h4v-1.9H7c-1.71 0-3.1-1.39-3.1-3.1zM8 13h8v-2H8v2zm9-6h-4v1.9h4c1.71 0 3.1 1.39 3.1 3.1s-1.39 3.1-3.1 3.1h-4V17h4c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5s-2.24-5-5-5z"/>
</g>
```