# Как определить что произошел клик по изображению нарисованному при помощи drawImage

Tags: java, swing

Есть элемент созданный с помощью `drawImage` и  какого-либо изображения. Хотелось бы узнать, как можно реализовать удаление элемента по клику на нём?

Это то же самое, что, допустим, удалить изображение при щелчке на нём. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, я собрал пример, как в по ссылке в комментарии...

Каждому изображению присваивается цветовой идентификатор и создается дополнительная картинка-буфер в памяти, в которой каждое изображение представлено областью закрашенной в цвет-идентификатор. по клику берем цвет и по нему определяем что за картинка была под мышкой.

При таком подходе технически возможно обработать клик по картинкам с прозрачностью, при этом цветом идентификатором в пикинг буфере не надо красить полностью прозрачные пиксели, это слегка сложнее и в этом примере я не стал так делать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
public class PickingExample {
    
        static class Elem extends Point {
            Image img;
            Elem() throws IOException {
                this.img =  ImageIO.read(new File("./1.gif"));
                this.x = (int) (Math.random()*300);
                this.y = (int) (Math.random()*200);
            }
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Map<Color, Elem> elements = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
                elements.put(new Color( i, 0, 0), new Elem());
            BufferedImage pickingBuffer = new BufferedImage(400, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JComponent comp = new JComponent() {
                @Override
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    Graphics pick = pickingBuffer.getGraphics();
                    for (Color pickColor : elements.keySet()) {
                        Elem element = elements.get(pickColor);
                        pick.setColor(pickColor);
                        pick.fillRect(element.x, element.y, element.img.getWidth(null), element.img.getHeight(null));
                        g.drawImage(element.img, element.x, element.y, element.img.getWidth(null), element.img.getHeight(null), null);
                    }
                    pick.dispose();
                }
            };
            f.add(comp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            f.setSize(400, 300);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
            comp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    elements.remove(new Color(pickingBuffer.getRGB(e.getX(), e.getY())));
                    f.repaint();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

PS: такой же фокус применяю и в некоторых случаях в 3д приложениях, для тех же самых целей, тут тоже создается картинка-буфер и специальный шейдер, который так же кодирует объекты по цветам.

---

в этих ответах использован тот же прием:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/988105/188366

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/962780/188366

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь что никак.

После вызова `drawImage` изображение уже преобразовано в байты и отрисовано. Java не запоминает ни какое это было изображение ни где оно было нарисовано.

Так что часть работы придется сделать самому:

Один вариант: запоминать координаты, в которых были нарисованы изображения, обрабатывать щелчок, находить пересечение и перерисовывать эту область. Отдельно обрабатывать случаи «накладок» одного изображения поверх другого.

Второй вариант: вместо того чтобы отрисовывать изображения на графике реализовать их в виде отдельных компонентов. Компонент можно написать целиком самописный, либо использовать встроенные (посмотрите как добавить JLabel с картинкой здесь: [How to add an image to a JPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706730)).

Преимущество второго подхода в том, что отслеживание щелчка мыши и накладок Swing сделает сам.

Comment: это можно слелать по принципу как я это сделал в этом ответе (js) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/962780/188366 основная идея - иметь back buffer размером с видимую область экрана, в котором содержится цветовая карта объектов в виде текстуры, но это чревато отрисовкой еще одного дополнительного кадра. для проверки на что же наведена мышка при таком подходе достаточно считать цвет пикселя из этого буфера и сравнить его с картой соответствия цветов и объектов... я в принципе могу собрать аналогичный пример для swing

Comment: у этого подхода есть приемущество пред математической проверкой коллизии с прямоугольником - можно откинуть прозрачные пиксели

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Отлично! Готовый вариант есть. Опубликуйте ответом, даже не переписывая на Swing. Краткого объяснения будет достаточно.

Comment: Собрал пример на swing, попозже еще описание добавлю...