# Создание своей панорамы с использованием JavaScript API Яндекc

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Необходимо создать свою панораму (например своей квартиры), прогуляться по ней. Для этого хочу использовать JavaScript API Яндекc.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что это может работать и в оффлайн режиме?

Comment: яндекс не сильно нужен.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1001952/188366

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript API Яндекс.Карт для работы требует подключения к интернету, так как сам программный код и все вспомогательные ресурсы будут скачиваться при просмотре страницы с панорамой. Поэтому оффлайн панораму так сделать не получится.

Что касается в принципе создания панорам из собственных снимков, то у Яндекса есть [пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/panorama_with_connections?from=SO) и подробное [руководство](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/panoramas/custom-panorama-docpage/?from=SO) по подготовке снимка.