# Геометрические преобразоваия плоскости на сферу?

Tags: геометрия

Есть плоское изображение - географическая карта Земли. С помощью каких трансформаций и матриц преобразования, можно визуально, придать ей объем в виде шарообразности. Т.е, трансформировать двухмерное изображение так, будто оно натянуто на сферу, или сфера - позади изображения и выпирая, придает центру плоскости - шарообразности.
Как называется такой вид проекции/трансформации, что можно специализированного почитать на эту тему?

Comment: тут есть пример реализации  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613680/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начни от обратного, с проекций шара на плоскость.

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Картографическая_проекция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_картографических_проекций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: @Дмытрык с мобильного копипастил... сломалось - исправил